# Typescript type inference of return dict keys based on supplied parameters

Tags: typescript

I have the following files:

*types.ts*

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';

export interface ApiSpec {
    [apiReq: string]: (...args: any[]) => {
        url: string;
        contentType?: string;
        query?: {
            [key: string]: any;
        };
        method?: string;
    };
}

export type ApiRequest = {
    [T in keyof ApiSpec]: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>;
};
```

*Api.ts*

```
import {ApiSpec, ApiRequest} from './types';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export default function createApi(apiSpec: ApiSpec, concurrent: boolean = false): ApiRequest {
    return _.mapValues(apiSpec, (fn, name) => {
        return function(...args) {
            const requestSpec = fn.apply(null, args);
            requestSpec.which = name;
            requestSpec.url = `http://localhost:8989/api${requestSpec.url}`;
            // request is a function doing the API request and returning a bluebird promise
            return request(requestSpec, concurrent);
        }
    });
}
```

*main.ts*

```
import createApi from './Api';

// usually defined in a separate file
const ApiSpec = {
    fetchData: (start: Date, end: Date) => {
        return {
            url: `/fetchData?start=${start}&end=${end}`
        };
    }
};
const Api = createApi(ApiSpec);

Api.fetchData(new Date(), new Date()).then(res => {
    // do something with result
})
```

Is it possible in typescript to have type completion for my `Api` variable? I would like to be able to know which functions are available in my API and most importantly the parameters of each API call without having to look at the file where the API spec is defined. However, just using `[T in keyof ApiSpec]` in the types cannot infer the exact keys of the API spec I'm passing to `createApi`. Is this somehow possible in typescript?

Note: I'm using version 2.3.4 and cannot update to the latest typescript version at the moment

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for dev-time type completion from a run-time data source. Have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a generic type parameter to capture the actual type passed in to `createApi` and map that in `ApiRequest` instead of the generic `ApiSpec`. `ApiSpec` can be used as the type constraint for the type parameter.

```
export interface ApiSpec {
    [apiReq: string]: (...args: any[]) => {
        url: string;
        contentType?: string;
        query?: {
            [key: string]: any;
        };
        method?: string;
    };
}

export type ApiRequest<T extends ApiSpec> = {
    [P in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[P]>) => Promise<any>;
};



export default function createApi<T extends ApiSpec>(apiSpec: T, concurrent: boolean = false): ApiRequest<T> {
    return null!; // implementation 
}
// usually defined in a separate file
const ApiSpec = {
    fetchData: (start: Date, end: Date) => {
        return {
            url: `/fetchData?start=${start}&end=${end}`
        };
    }
};
const Api = createApi(ApiSpec);

Api.fetchData(new Date(), new Date()).then(res => {
    // do something with result
})
```

**Note** I also added the `Parameters<T[P]>` in order to preserve argument types in the resulting object.

**Edit**
For the version of typescript you are using (2.3), we don't have conditional types or tuples in rest parameters, so there is no way to map the function parameters in a type safe way unfortunately. The best we can do is :

```
export type ApiRequest<T extends ApiSpec> = {
    [P in keyof T]: (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>;
};
```

Comment: What is `Parameters`? I get the `Cannot find name Parameters` error

Comment: @XeniaSis what version of ts are you using ? `Parameters` I think was added in 3.2 (or 3.1) but the definition for it `type Parameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;` should work for 3.0 and above

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I'm using v2.3

Comment: @XeniaSis that is pretty old, let me see if I can get something similar to work on that version (it will be pretty ugly though). Sorry I missed the version in the question

Comment: @XeniaSis added a version that works for 2.3,  there are just too many things missing, we have to use `...args: any[]` for the parameters there is no better option, but the names are mapped as expected. You really should update to a newer version a lot has happened since 2.3 :)

Comment: Nice! I have type completion for the API functions but the parameters are not typed. I guess that's because I can't use `Parameters`, right?

Comment: @XeniaSis yes. Newer versions of ts get better at type mappings, conditional types and tuples in test parameter were HUGE leaps forward. Without those there are limited things we can do. Again, if you can update :)

Comment: It's in the plans to update. So thanks for the answer that covers both versions :)